# When are released objects finally destroyed?

Tags: objective-c, memory, pool, dealloc

When you release an object in Objective-C (assuming its release count is 1) its release count is decremented to 0 and the dealloc method called. Is the object destroyed right there and then after the [super dealloc], or is it added to the pool and destroyed when the pool is drained?

I would assume that released objects are destroyed at the end of dealloc (when [super dealloc] is called) I know autorelease variables are added to the pool, just wanted to be sure what happens to normal released objects.

cheers -gary-

Comment: Sorry Rafal, Edited to include Objective-C

Comment: Its really worth mentioning here, that the retain count never actually hits 0. When you do the final release, decementing the 1 to a 0 is a waste of a CPU cycle (:

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First off, Objective-C the *programming language* does not have any concept of memory management. Memory management is built into Foundation *(the common framework of Cocoa for Mac OS X and Cocoa Touch on iPhone OS)*. Foundation adds a rootclass NSObject that implements `alloc`, `retain`, `release` and `autorelease` as convenience wrappers on top of `class_createInstance()` and `object_dispose()` functions from the Objective-C run-time.

Since Objective-C is memory management agnostic, adding garbage collection and making all memory management methods on `NSObject` no-ops was quite easy. But there is no garbage collection on iPhone OS and legacy Mac OS X and there we instead use a reference counting scheme in Cocoa.

An object is created when calling the `alloc` class method on `NSObject` or `NSProxy` from Foundation. These default implementations will call `class_createInstance()` so that you never need to manually.

An object "dies" when `dealloc` is run on the root class `NSObject`. This is when the memory for the object on the heap is released by calling `object_dispose()`, you will never need to call this function yourself as long as you inherit from `NSObject` or `NSProxy` from Foundation.

Autoreleased objects are not treated any special as far as the run-time is concerned, an *autoreleased* object is just as alive as any other object. What happens when you `autorelease` an object is approximately;

```
-(id)autorelease; {
  [NSAutoreleasePool addObject:self];  // retain count +1
  [self release];                      // retain count -1
  return self;
}
```

Calling `autorelease` will not decrement the retain count, it will just transfer ownership of the object from the caller to the current autorelease pool. Later when the current autorelease pool goes away, it will call `release` on all of the objects it owns, and any object no longer owned by anything else is released.

Comment: So in Objective-C is there always a dealloc method even if a custom one is not defined. That would seem to make sense, release object, retain count goes to 0, dealloc called, [super dealloc] called, object dead?

Comment: Yes and No. I have edited my answer to clarify the difference between Objective-C and Cocoa.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, they are deallocated as soon as the retain-count hits zero.

The autorelease system is for objects who's ownership is a little "ambiguous" - i.e. when you're returning a fresh object that you don't want to own, whose lifetime is unknown, and you don't want to assume the caller will take responsibility for. When the autorelease pool is drained (generally next time around the run-loop), all members are sent release. If the caller who received your object wants to take responsibility for it, all it need do is retain it, and this will avoid its deallocation.

Comment: So [object release]; Release count set to 0; dealloc called (to release any instance variables); object deallocated; .... does that sound right?

Comment: Yup, sounds right to me. Of course, custom dealloc implementations can do whatever they like.

Comment: The current threads autorelease pool is drained at the end of the current run-loop, not the next run. This is important as otherwise this thread could keep memory for a very long time while waiting for timers, user events and other run-loop sources.